# Machine only boots if I go through recovery mode

Tags: boot

On a fresh install of 20.04, I cannot boot through the normal menu. If I go through `Ubuntu (Advanced Options)`, I can select the latest kernel with recovery mode, and it boots into the recovery menu. From there, I can hit `resume`, and my machine will boot. I've now set up GRUB to boot straight into the recovery option, and it works, but is obviously not ideal. This machine had a previously working 20.04 install that just stopped booting overnight, hence the reinstall. All of this assumes I can even get to the grub menu, which looks like it's about 50/50 odds at this point. It's irrelevant here, but I feel I should also mention that I couldn't get the Windows install (on a different hard disk, not a partition, in the same box) to boot either.

Comment: Do you get a (error) message when you boot through the normal menu? Did you install new software/updates?

Comment: Sounds like some hardware has or is dying in the computer.  Do you hear any beeps when computer powering up?  With having similar problem with Windows and Ubuntu, problem is usually more related to hardware than to OS.  With two hard drives, they can be placed near bottom of list of hard ware giving problem.

Comment: @Kevin no error messages, just a blank screen

Comment: @crip659 That's what I'm thinking to, but I don't know what the culprit could be besides the motherboard. If the RAM were dying, I'd get a bunch of inconsistent errors, the GPU has worked throughout my troubleshooting, and the only thing left in the box is the PSU, which would be obvious if it failed.

Comment: PSU might be starting to fail, not failed completely.or a cap on MB might be gone.  Could also be a cable that is just a touch loose.  If possible remove hard drive and try it on another computer, just to be sure.  Ubuntu won't give a hissy fit like windows might.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the motherboard (CPU also got replaced, but I doubt that was the culprit) ended up fixing this issue for me. Posting for posterity.